# Can not set my own SMS app as default. Any suggestion how to solve it?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have written a simple SMS app that is used for test purposes.
The intent filter looks like as below:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  <!-- "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>


        <!-- Sends text to someone .This will enable any Text Share functionality-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However, when I install the app on the phone, go to settings->default apps ->messages I can see the other message apps and choose which of them to make the default app. 
But my app is not visible in the list. Why is my app not visible? I guess it has to do with the intent filter

Comment: The intent filter for my activity is identical to the one you mentioned. So for me it is still a mystery why it is not working

Comment: Identical? Not really. :-) Also, you were missing several other required elements, as the answer there indicates you _must_ provide. Anyhoo, you apparently got it figured out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I soved it by modifying my AndroidManifest file according to below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name=".MMSReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>"></receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".SMSReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <service
            android:name=".SmsService"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
    enter code here

</manifest>
```

See https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html